# Phalcon PHP - How to make friendly url?

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I made routing pattern as following:

```
$router->add('/album/view/{slug}-:int', array(
'controller' => 'album',
'action' => 'view',
'id' => 2,))->setName('album-view');
```

But it didnt work, so I changed the pattern to:

```
$router->add('/album/view/{slug}/:int', array(
'controller' => 'album',
'action' => 'view',
'id' => 2,))->setName('album-view');
```

And it worked perfectly!

So how to make routing pattern `'/album/view/{slug}-:int'` in Phalcon router? Thank for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation says](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html#defining-routes):

> /:int    /([0-9]+)    Matches an integer parameter

Meaning it actually expects `/:int`, not just `:int`. Just use named params with custom regex?

```
$router->add(
    '/album/view/{slug}-([0-9]+)',
    array(
        'controller' => 'album',
        'action'     => 'view',
        'id'         => 1, // ([0-9]+)
    )
);
```

I didn't test this, but must be along those lines.